# How to add dependency Hbase to nutch project?

Tags: maven, ivy, nutch

Recently I want to modify nutch's code(Fetcher.java) to save the raw html page into Hbase. I have import the project into Eclipse. But I'm not familiar with ant, ivy, maven or buildfile.

How do I add the Hbase library jar file into the project so that I can use ant to build it?

Comment: what have you tried so far? this question is very broad and can not be answered in its current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I made it, by adding a dependency declaration in ivy.xml file. And the library description can be fond in http://search.maven.org/. Then just run ant in command shell.(for my case, running ant in Eclipse does not work. I don't know why.)
The question may be trivial, but I hope this helpful for the beginners like me.

Comment: <target name="clean-lib" description="--> clean the project

Comment: this target causes the auto deletion of libraries from the lib folder before compilation. You could modify it to not delete yr hbase jar or copy hbase jar right in the end of that target

Comment: There's an ivy eclipse plugin which you might find interesting for managing the Eclipse classpaths

Answer (score 0):

Add the hbase jars to buildpath in your eclipse project and ensure that the jar is copied in the lib folder inside nutch.

Comment: It does not work. When I rebuild the project, The jar file in build/lib directory will disappear. Should I modify ivy.xml or pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give this in detail:

Add the following line to ivysettings.xml of Nutch:

```
<module organisation="org.apache.giraph" name=".*" resolver="internal"/>
```

Add the following lines to ivy.xml of Nutch:

```
    <dependency org="org.apache.giraph" name="giraph" rev="1.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
      conf="*->default" />
    <dependency org="org.apache.giraph" name="giraph-hbase" rev="1.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
      conf="*->default" />
    <dependency org="org.apache.giraph" name="giraph-examples" rev="1.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
      conf="*->default" />
```

Now create put jar files under .ivy2 subfolders:

```
/home/emre/.ivy2/local/org.apache.giraph/giraph/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/giraph.jar
/home/emre/.ivy2/local/org.apache.giraph/giraph-hbase/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/giraph-hbase.jar
/home/emre/.ivy2/local/org.apache.giraph/giraph-examples/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/jars/giraph-examples.jar
```